# Question got migrated from Law.SE and closed as off-topic

Tags: support

I asked a question on Law.SE, but a moderator (I'm guessing) thought it would be more suited at Politics.SE, so he/she/it migrated it, then it got closed as off-topic. -.-

I agree it isn't suited for Politics.SE but also yield to a moderator's opinion.

So what, now?

[The Question in question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/what-is-the-logic-of-dnrs-existence)

Comment: @ᴡᴏʀᴅs, heh I don't mind it being OOS of both sites, but I agree what you said would have been the proper way. Should I do something, now?

Comment: I think it is about time we better define the difference between politics.SE and law.SE. I see a lot of questions which are IMO posted on the wrong site, but also others which are sent to the other even though they IMO don't belong there.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the question so we can form our own opinion about where it belongs?

Comment: I created [a new question with the goal to draw a clearer line between politics.SE and law.SE](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/which-questions-belong-to-law-se-and-which-to-politics-se).

Comment: @Philipp, feedback taken into action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Typical policy (perhaps unwritten) is for the site mod to ask the target site mod if the question is in-scope **before the migration**.
- Having said that, regrading [your own specific questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/what-is-the-logic-of-dnrs-existence), imho you have 2 options (stealing from my own comment):

  1. keeping it as-is, it's not about politics per se. However, there's a chance it is suited - with perhaps minor changes - to **either philosophy.SE or Health.SE**. Your best bet would be to ask on those sites' chat or Meta before asking on main site and if they sound positive, **post there**.
  2. However, while the existence of DNR orders by itself isn't a political thing, some aspects of the issue are political, e.g. the lack of existence of laws prohibiting them. So **adjusting the question to ask about political aspects would make it possible to bring it in-scope here and get re-opened**.

Comment: meh, I'll leave it to die